# Convert varchar(50) to Date Format 'yyyy-mm-dd' in teradata?

Tags: teradata

I have a column defined as `Date` format `yyyy-mm-dd` while creating.

I want to insert data from other table which has that column as `varchar(50)`

While selecting and inserting into the table I got this error

> INSERT Failed. 2665:  Invalid date.

Can someone help me in casting this?

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLES.FACT
(

CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID, 
LOB_START_DATE, 

)

SEL  
CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID,
I.start_date   as LOB_START_DATE,

FROM  #LOGIN I

left join JOURNEY_TABLE.DOTCOM_DIM d1
on I.PAGES = d1.PAGE_DESC
```

This is the example of date stored in varchar(50) field : 2014-04-03

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the actual Insert statement?

Comment: Can you post an example of a date that is stored in VARCHAR(50) field?

Comment: Stored like this 2014-04-03...

Comment: First thing I'd do would be to substring out just the first 10 characters from that column, since you know a date can't be more than 10 bytes.  But if you've got anything in there that is invalid for a date, it's going to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it would be helpful, here's a query that should allow you to identify the rows with invalid dates:

```
select
*
from
#login t1
left outer join sys_calendar.calendar t2
on t1.start_date =  cast (cast(t2.calendar_date as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD') as char(10))
where t2.calendar_date is null
```

Any rows that return from this query will have invalid dates.

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need is the `format` statement

[examples here](http://teradataforum.com/l040409a.htm)

```
SEL  
CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID,
cast(((I.start_date (date, format 'yyyy-mm-dd'))(char(10))) as LOB_START_DATE,
```

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Teradata there is a TRYCAST() function. This function will attempt to cast the data and return `NULL` if the conversion fails, instead of failing the statement.

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLES.FACT
(
CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID, 
LOB_START_DATE, 
)
SELECT Customer_Account_ID
     , TRYCAST(I.Start_Date AS DATE) AS LOB_START_DATE
FROM  #LOGIN I
LEFT JOIN JOURNEY_TABLE.DOTCOM_DIM d1
  ON I.Pages = d1.Page_Desc;
```